# youtube playback problem

Tags: youtube

I am having a hard time watching youtube as of now, till yesterday I was able to watch youtube on my browser just fine(laptop).

However now when I play any video on youtube it just starts pausing and resuming, literally I can see the pause and play flash on my screen and my network is fine, also the same issue with my windows media player. How may I resolve this issue on my windows 8 laptop?

Any effort to help me resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.